# find the height of the aircraft

Tags: qnh

The elevation of Airport A is 150ft AMSL and Airport B is 500FT AMSL. The QNH at A is 1013hPa and at B is 998hPa. An aircraft is overhead A with 5000ft indicated on the altimeter with 1013hPa set on the subscale, and sets heading en-route directly to B. If the altimeter subscale and indicated altitude remain unchanged, what will the height of the aircraft be overhead B (Assume 1hPa = 30ft)

Comment: Welcome to the site. We don't mind helping with homework questions as long as someone shows that they have tried to solve it themselves and has run into a problem. Please edit and show your thinking and math.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this has been answered in the comments, here's a fuller explanation:

The altitude of the aircraft at A is 5000 ft. The air pressure falls as it travels to B, so to maintain the same pressure altitude it must descend. The QNH falls by 15Hpa, so working from the figures in the question the aircraft descends 450ft. So far, so good.

Note, however, that the questions asks for the **height** above Airfield B, not the altitude. Height is referenced from ground level, and B is at 500ft.

Thus, the height is 5000ft, minus 450ft due to pressure, minus 500ft due to airfield elevation.

The correct answer is 4050ft.